# XMLWriter getting stuck sometimes PHP

Tags: php, xml, xmlwriter

I have a regular XMLWriter structure and its working fine, my problem is that sometimes its getting stuck in the middle of the loop and stops looping but sometimes is it going ok through the end of the loop, what can be the problem of this structure.

```
$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openMemory();
$xml->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->startElement('rows');
$xml->writeElement('TotalRows', count($total));

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $xml->startElement('row');
    $xml->writeElement('id',  $row['fba_sku']);
    $xml->writeElement('sku', $row['sku']);

    // There is 31 elements with calculations

    if (0 == $i%1000) {
        file_put_contents('example.xml', $xml->flush(true), FILE_APPEND);
    }
}

$xml->endElement();
file_put_contents('example.xml', $xml->flush(true), FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: Hint: Instead of [`XMLWriter::openMemory()`](http://php.net/xmlwriter_open_memory) use [`XMLWriter::openURI()`](http://php.net/xmlwriter_open_uri) to write directly to the file. XMLWriter will do the buffered writes for you transparently, so you can remove the `file_put_contents` calls. Just call [`XMLWriter::flush()`](http://php.net/xmlwriter_flush) at the end.

Comment: Also double check the position of `$xml->endElement();`, it should be on the same level as `$xml->startElement('row');` but it is not.